# Angular 2 Google places autocomplete event listener not responding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I have an input field with Google places autocomplete. Everything works as expected, but the event listener is not responding once a selection is made from the autocomplete dropdown. Shouldn't that be the expected behavior? Here is my code.

```
let input: any = this.geocodeTest.nativeElement;
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            console.log('listening');
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
        })
    });
```

The code currently lives within the ngOnit()

Comment: Sorry for the idiotic question. instead of "places_changed", it is supposed to be "place_changed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are running these code in `ngOnInit`, and this is the reason because DOM elements are only avalible after `AfterViewInit` lifehook.

you have to move your code to `ngAfterViewInit`.

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/OCUtOSCWpx37Lv5qdcFk?p=preview).

Comment: The method for the function was incorrect. It was supposed to be "place_changed" instead of "places_changed". However, you are probably right about placing the code into ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: @DavidAguirre thanks for that. also you are using wrong name for `searhBox.getPlaces()`, it's `searchBox.getPlace()` :)